# Python: ncurses not printing a value passed to function

Tags: python, user-interface, ncurses, curses

I'm writing a ncurses GUI for an app. I have following code in a file `admin.py`:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import curses.textpad

from gui_helpers import *
import global_vars as g

def parse_command(win, command):
    # print_str(win, 0, 0, command)
    if command == "help":
        print_str(win, 1, 1, "Available commands: add - adds a board, list - lists boards, mkdir - makes board directory")

def display_admin_screen(win, keypress):
    rows = win.getmaxyx()[0]
    cols = win.getmaxyx()[1]

    print_str_center(win, 0, 1, "Admin interface", g.RED|g.BOLD)
    print_str(win, 1, 0, "Command line")

    textpad_win = win.subwin(1, cols - 1, 3, 1)
    output_win = win.subwin(5, cols - 1, 5, 1)

    output_win.refresh()
    textpad_win.refresh()
    win.refresh()

    curses.curs_set(1)
    textpad = curses.textpad.Textbox(textpad_win)
    textpad.stripspaces = 0
    textpad_win.move(0,0)
    textpad.edit()

    command = textpad.gather()
    parse_command(output_win, command)
    # print_str(output_win, 0, 0, command)
    textpad_win.clear()
    curses.curs_set(0)
```

The code itself (the function `display_admin_screen()`) runs in a loop in file `gui.py` which has all the necessary library imports:

```
while True:    
        keypress = stdscr.getch()
        display_title_bar(stdscr)

        if g.STATE == 'motd':
            display_motd(working_win, keypress)
        elif g.STATE == 'boards':
            boards_view.display_threads(working_win, g.SELECTED_BOARD, keypress)
        elif g.STATE == 'admin':
            admin.display_admin_screen(working_win, keypress)

        working_win.refresh()
        stdscr.refresh()
```

The problem I'm having is that when I type 'help' in the textbox in `admin.py`, nothing happens. It should display help text in `output_win`. I've checked that the value gets passed to function `parse_command()` properly, and that it is a proper value. I thought it may be the problem with creating subwindows inside a loop, so I tried creating them in `gui.py` outside of the loop and passing them to the function, but to no avail. If I just tell the `parse_command()` function to write something to the output window it does that no problem. For some reason the `if` block seems to be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out what was wrong. After pressing Enter, there was a bunch of whitespace (not newline `\n`) appended to the command. All I had to do was change:

```
command = textpad.gather()
```

to

```
command = textpad.gather().strip()
```

And it works now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your program reads from the standard screen using

```
stdscr.getch()
```

which does a refresh on `stdscr` that can overwrite any of the other windows (such as `output_win`).  To work around this, you should call [`.getch()`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h3-Reading-characters) using a window which you would prefer *is* updated.

If it is awkward to do that, you could use [`.touchwin()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.touchwin) and [`wrefresh()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.refresh) to force a given window to repaint.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not the case. I've tried commenting out `stdscr.getch()` completely, moving it around the loop, and even commenting out `stdscr.refresh()` but nothing helped. The `if command == "help":` block for some reason doesn't get executed, while the function itself is called with proper arguments.